# Получить значения input через Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить значение input через jquery, но только в нужном блоке.

Вот код разметки:

```
<div>
   <a href="#" class="add_cart">Добавить в корзину</a>
   <input type="hidden" value="Компьютер 1" name="title"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="1600" name="price"/>
</div>
<div>
     <a href="#" class="add_cart">Добавить в корзину</a>
     <input type="hidden" value="Компьютер 2" name="title"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="2600" name="price"/>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="add_cart">Добавить в корзину</a>
  <input type="hidden" value="Компьютер 3" name="title"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="3600" name="price"/>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на "Добавить в корзину" я получал значение input в текущем блоке div.

Как правильнее реализовать, потому что присваивать inputam разные id - не вариант, т.к. записей может быть много.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $('.add_cart').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input[name=title]').val() //вернет значения inputa'a
    })
```

Comment: А если у нас 1000 элементов на странице, на каждый будем навешивать событие? Лучше использовать делегирование.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_cart', function() {
    var $currentBlock = $(this).closest('div'),
        title = $currentBlock.find('[name="title"]'),
        price = $currentBlock.find('[name="price"]');
});
```